# iOS development - how views reflect in-app settings on the fly

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode, cocoa-touch

I'm new to ios development, and have made a simple app.

It contains a root view controller (a table view consists of a list of cells, clicking cell leads to a content view) and another in-app settings view controller holds several simple UI controls like switch, slider to save application related settings. After user changes something, application simply writes to file for persistence.

My question is, how to make other view controllers reflect changes in settings?

My thought is when app loads, I initialize all settings to a dictionary and keep it in memory. When change happens I also update that dictionary besides writing to file. Each time my content view shows I ask it to always load that settings dictionary.

For example, if user change font size in settings view, I want content view controllers get notified and hereby change font size immediately next time it's shown to user.

I dont know if I'm supposed to make my custom delegate/data source.

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use [NSUserDefaults](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSUserDefaults_Class/Reference/Reference.html) to store and retrieve app settings. That's exactly what it's made for, and it will take care of automatically saving settings to disk and retrieving them later for you.

As for updating other parts of the app when settings change, you have a number of options. On iOS, one fairly easy approach is to register for the NSUserDefaultsDidChangeNotification in any view controllers that need to know about and react to settings changes. Then, when that notification is received, update to reflect the new settings.

Comment: NSUserDefaults should be used to save user preferences. I would use it to store the font size so that the font size stays the same on next launch. However, I wouldn't use it to send notifications to ViewControllers.

Comment: I'm not suggesting using it to send notifications to view controllers. I'm talking about view controllers signing up to be notified when NSUserDefaults change -- no matter what causes the change -- then reacting accordingly. It's an important design difference. It keeps various parts of the code loosely coupled, which is often a good idea. Finer grained notifications may be desirable, in which case they can be manually posted. FWIW, NSUserDefaults changes can be observed using KVO on 10.7+ or with NSUserDefaultsController on 10.3+. KVO of NSUserDefaults may work on iOS too (not 100% sure).

Comment: +1 @Andrew for NSUserDefaultsDidChangeNotification to update changes **dynamically** for views (though may be a bit overkill for OP). However, on viewWillAppear: of each VC I would manually read the settings from NSUserDefaults just for security in case one of those VC's hasn't yet been initialized (and therefore isn't listening for those notifications).

Comment: @Ireichold, yes, I should have mentioned that in my answer. One should always read the current values upon initialization.

Comment: Thanks! NSUserDefaults seems exactly what I need.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you're trying to send various ViewControllers a notification when something changes in another ViewController. You have two options:

1. **Multiple ViewControllers**: You can post a notification using NSNotificationCenter and any ViewController that is observing for that specific notification will be notified. More info: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Notifications/Introduction/introNotifications.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000043i
2. **Single ViewController**: If only a single ViewController needs to be notified, you use delegation to notify the ViewController. More info: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CocoaFundamentals/CommunicatingWithObjects/CommunicateWithObjects.html